# Matplotlib: interactive plot on a web server

Tags: python, django, web-applications, matplotlib

I'm currently using [Open Flash Chart 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) on my django website, but I find it insufficiently customizable. (It's great when you want the usual barcharts, piecharts, but what about homemade shapes...). Although it's open source, I don't feel like diving in the Flex code.

I'm thinking a lot about matplotlib but the [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/howto_faq.html?highlight=web#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server) is rather poor on web application developpment.

Does anybody uses matplotlib in his web app?
I would appreciate links on those web sites to figure out what can be achieved.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use [MPLD3](https://mpld3.github.io/) to export your existing matplotlib stuff to browser.
Matplotlib itself is very powerful, albeit, I agree the documentation is not very extensive.
I've learned it just by trying stuff out and finding examples on the net.
'matplotlib example X' where X is somewhat about what you are trying to plot find suprising amount of code on the net.