# How to embed an interactive matplotlib plot in a webpage

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, html

I have been searching how to embed an interactive matplotlib widget (like this one: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) in a webpage. The final aim is to make an educational page.

I hope I am not duplicating the question. What google finds is always how to embed the plot as a still-shot, in an image format.

I thought I can do something with *ipython notebook* or *plotly* or *gjango*. But I got confused.

Is it possible at all for intractive plots? 
I appreciate your guides to which direction I should think and work on.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `webagg` matplotlib backend? Also, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354883/matplotlib-interactive-plot-on-a-web-server

Comment: This question has been asked in 2014, would appreciate if someone could please re-visit this question now and help understand if it is now possible to embed an interactive matplotlib widget into a webpage? Is learning D3 the only way out?

Comment: Researching this is in 2020 and this post still seems to be the most relevant. Any news?

Answer (score 13):

In summer 2015, I'm facing a similar task: embed interactive widgets that change their underlying data when the slider is moved. This is very similar to [interactive IPython widgets](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Index.ipynb) which are interactive when run on a local machine. Examples of what I want can be found [jakevdp's blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/).

To summarize work done so far:

- [ipywidgets-static](https://github.com/jakevdp/ipywidgets) converts interactive IPython widgets to static HTML. However, this library is no longer maintained. Development has moved to [ipython/ipywidgets](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets).
- IPython is working on [ipython/ipywidgets](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets). They have a [Github issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/issues/16#issuecomment-105725797) to make these widgets static and to be embedded in a standalone HTML file.
- [HoloViews](http://ioam.github.io/holoviews/) provides some interactive slider options that can be embedded in a static HTML file (using IPython's nbconvert)
- [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) plots that rely on interactive sliders [require a server](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/quickstart.html#bokeh-plot-server).
- [plot.ly](https://plot.ly) doesn't support sliders/etc. I believe this is true based off this [blog post](http://moderndata.plot.ly/widgets-in-ipython-notebook-and-plotly/).
- [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io) converts between matplotlib and d3. I believe this library supports panning and zooming, not sliders/interactivity. Here's a [related Github issue](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/79)

There's also blog post titled "[Scientific Python in the browser: it's coming!](http://cyrille.rossant.net/scientific-python-in-the-browser-its-coming/)". This post was dated 2014-3-31.

For me, the two most attractive options are ipywidgets and HoloViews but I'm looking forward to when IPython provides static interactive widgets. I expect to see solid support for static interactive widgets quickly and in less that 5 years/2020 (and in 2 years/2017?).

Comment: matplotlib also has it's own widgets and zhe work with the nbagg and webagg backends.

Answer (score 2):

As of Early April 2014 the answer is yes. Based on the work going on in this space, I expect the quality and quantity of such libraries to continue to improve very quickly.

IPython 2.0, specifically the notebook, supports [interactive controls](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/whatsnew/version2.0.html#interactive-widgets), which was covered in some detail by Brian Granger in his talk [IPython - The Attributes of Software and How They Affect Our Work](http://vimeo.com/79832657) (see from 32:25 onward for the bits you're interested in)

There are some amazing projects being worked on at the moment that combine server and client side code for the next generation of python visualisation libraries. At the moment this includes the work on [MPLD3](http://mpld3.github.io/) and the [ipywidgets](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/05/static-interactive-widgets/) library. There are some great interactive plots on Jake Vanderplas' blog [Pythonic Perambulations](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/01/10/d3-plugins-truly-interactive/) that show demonstrate this.