# Create a Live Streaming StockChart and Live Streaming Stock Tickers

Tags: api, charts, streaming, finance, stocks

How do I create a Live Streaming Stock Chart and Live Streaming Stock Tickers like on Yahoo Finance, CNBC, Google Finance, Bloomberg etc.? Where do I start? 
Web development, language Javascript, I want to build live stock quotes on my website.

Comment: This question is much too broad. You haven't even specified which platform you'll be using (web, desktop application, mobile app, etc), nor the language.

Comment: Web development, language Javascript, I want to build live streaming stock quotes on my website.

Comment: Did some looking around found some interactive java charts, http://www.jqplot.com/index.php http://www.highcharts.com/ http://d3js.org/ http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 I guess creating chart template is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend watching this series (it's in Python):
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcR-u9O8LyLR7URiKuW-XZq

Technologies, which I use for similar purposes are Python with matplotlib and numpy modules. There is a link for a related topic: [Matplotlib: interactive plot on a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354883/matplotlib-interactive-plot-on-a-web-server). 
It's probably doable in JS, but using a general purpose language and a web framework could make it easier.

Comment: Upvote please, so others may easily see the answer too.